# Are $8, 36, 216,$ and $2304$ the only perfect powers that is $6$ less or more than a primorial?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

Are $8, 36, 216,$ and $2304$ the only perfect powers form of $p\#$$\pm6$, where $p\#$ is primorial?

I noticed that when I try to add or subtract $6$ from a primorial, the results are:

- $2+6=8$, which is a perfect cube.
- $30+6=36$, a perfect square.
- $210+6=216$, a perfect cube also.
- $2310-6=2304$, a perfect square number.

Note that I excluded trival examples.

My question is: Is these numbers are the only perfect powers that form of $p\#$$\pm6$, where $p\#$ is a primorial?
If so, it can be a perfect higher odd prime perfect power?

My knowledge is that $p\#$$\pm6$ is only a perfect square if $p\#$$\pm6$ is equal to $6\pmod{8}$, and $p\#$ must not be divisible by $13$, so that means there is no perfect square above $30030$ that is $6$ more or less than a primorial, but I don’t know if there is argument that can be used for cubes and higher odd powers.

Comment: Upto $p=3\cdot 10^5$ , there are no further perfect powers.

Comment: For $p\ge 5$, $6\mid (p\#\pm 6)$. If the result is a perfect power, call it $n^k$, then $6\mid n^k \Rightarrow 6^k \mid n^k \Rightarrow 6^k \mid (p\# \pm 6)$. That might happen only very rarely, if at all, other than the examples already identified, especially for larger exponents $k$.